# XML UI not displaying correctly on android - button and text input not displaying

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I have just started reading into android development so I am willing to bet there is a very simple solution to this..

I followed the guide on the Android developer site, building the sample UI. The graphical layout shows the button and text input box no problem so it does not seem to be an issue with the code. For some reason it does not display on the AVT or when I install the APK on a phone... I am using a Galaxy Nexus and set up the AVT as a Galaxy Nexus too.

I have updated the ADT and tried several things but I am assuming there is something I have maybe forgotten to configure? can someone help?

Im new to this so be nice ;)

here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

also please check if you have called setcontentview function in your activity passing this xml layout

Comment: Yeah it was the setcontentview not passing the xml layout. Thanks for your help!